# How to exchange mouse button in cuis smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I'd like to exchange button usage in Cuis smalltalk.
Currently the right mouse button brings up the alo, while the middle button shows the context menu.
Is it possible to switch such behaviours ?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `ButtonDecodeTable` in the image, or you can tell the VM to use a different mouse mapping. This depends on the platform:

- Windows: toggle `3ButtonMouse` setting in the VM's `*.ini` file, either by pressing F2 or manually, see http://squeakvm.org/win32/settings.html
- Unix: pass a command line argument `-swapbtn`
- Mac: edit the button mapping in `Info.plist`

Comment: Wonderful ! I've had seen that switch but I've not understood its function.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've found it.

It seems that in the method installMouseDecodeTable 
I need to swap the DecodeTable bits even on Windows 
(I'm working on windows 7, and the buttons are swapped)

```
"Create a decode table that swaps the lowest-order 2 bits if not on Windows.
This is to make right mouse button be the mouseButton2, i.e. open menus, and middle (wheel) button open halos (mouseButton3).
See #processEvent:"
```

If I force the switch, swapping the bits, (for example using a dummy platformname, or removing the test altogether), then the buttons work correctly.

(You need to save the image, close and reopen the program)

```
ButtonDecodeTable _ Smalltalk platformName = 'Dummy'
    ifTrue: [ ByteArray withAll: (0 to: 255) ]
    ifFalse: [
        ByteArray withAll:
            ((0 to: 255) collect: [ :ea |
                ((ea bitAnd: 1) << 1 bitOr: (ea bitAnd: 2) >> 1) bitOr: (ea bitAnd: 252) ]) ]
```